# Cloudkit limit with Subscription

Tags: fetch, cloudkit, subscription

I am not sure how the Cloud subscription make sense to me.

If my app subscribe to a data insert event, for example. Then the app needs to fetch the asset, when it gets the subscription data insert notification. However, fetch operation should be counted towards the Cloudkit request limit which is 40 requests/sec, which means if I have more than 40 users, I may run into problems because once a new data is there, all at once all users get subscription notification and try to fetch at the same time?

Did I mis-understand anything? How do I get around?